# identify wheteher the user touched sphere or not

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm developing an Android application. I'm also working with OpenGL graphics.

I have a sphere drawn on the screen and I want to let user move it when he touches over it.  If he touches outside the sphere nothing happens.

How can I detect when user touches over sphere?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in this case is to use gluUnproject twice, once with Z set to near and once with Z set to far, that will give you a ray going "into" the screen. If the ray intersects the sphere (kind of trivial), then the user has clicked it. Otherwise, not.

Alternatively, you could read back the z buffer value at that pixel (this will be a pipeline stall, but you could use the previous frame, and unless the animation is totally wild nobody will probably notice). That will give you a single point in 3D with gluUnproject. Which is even more trivial to test, because if it is on the sphere, then sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy+dz*dz) must be the radius. To account for rounding errors, you might want to compare <= 1.0001*radius or such.

And lastly, you could do an occlusion query with a 1x1 pixel viewport. This is not terribly useful with a sphere, since the collision checking is so much easier, but it may be something you want to do with a much more complex object that maybe has holes and where you need pixel precise detection.

Comment: For you're second idea, how would you read back the z buffer of the pixel? readPixels doesn't have access to the z-buffer on android.

Comment: Hmm... I did not know that you could not read the Z buffer on android (why, actually?). That admittedly somewhat concludes the second solution. There is a nVidia extension to copy depth to color for this, but I've searched whether that's available on any android devices, does not seem so. One thing that might still work would be using a framebuffer object (which OpenGL ES 2.0 supports as core, not sure whether 1.0 has an extension), though. This will require another final pass to bring the image on-screen. But it should allow you to attach a (readable) texture to the depth attachment.